# PyQt display 1 widget in 2 layouts?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'd like to add QLineEdit/checkbox/button in 2 layouts. So no matter which one I press in which ever window they both do the same thing, update each other as I type and so on.

Is it possible or do I need to create second set of controls and then signal link each other?

Regards
Dariusz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget can only exist in one place at a time. You will need to link the two unfortunately. Do yourself a favor and do it properly via a model.

If it were possible for a widget to exist in multiple places, this would lead to a whole lot of problems: cyclic trees, multiple parents, etc.

Comment: Thanks for info ! Had a though that was the case. Where can I read up on the model approach - thanks again !

Comment: @Dariusz: Maybe start with [the model-view programming guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). The model classes might be overkill, depending on your program. It could be enough for you to use a simple MVC approach: `WidgetA → SomeClass ← WidgetB`.